# url routing in mvc4 dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to resolve url in MVC but it gives me an unexpected url
suppose After successfully logged in Dashboard seen to user (http://localhost:6782/Dashboard/Index). I had create dynamic menu in the system that will be loaded on _Layout.cshtml. its code is as below

```
foreach (PROC_GET_MENU_BY_USER_Result subItem in subMenu)
                {
                    if (subMenu.IndexOf(subItem) == 0)
                    {
                        strMenu = strMenu + "<li  class ='haschildren'> <a href='#'>" + subItem.vDescription + "<span class='arrow'></span></a>";
                        strMenu = strMenu + "<ul class='submenu' style='z-index: 1;'>";
                    }

                    strMenu = strMenu + "<li><a href='" + subItem.vUrl + "'>" + subItem.vDescription + " </a>";

                    if (subMenu.IndexOf(subItem) == subMenu.Count - 1)
                    {
                        strMenu = strMenu + "</ul> ";
                        strMenu = strMenu + "</li>";
                    }
                }
```

And respected menu routing is defined in database.
Suppose if I Clicked any of the menu from dynamic menu it always consider "Dashboard" in the link

eg. suppose I click on "*Create Voucher*" link it looks like (/localhost:6782/Dashboard/Voucher/Create) instead of (/localhost:6782/Voucher/Create)

Please help me to resolve this.....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `subItem.vUrl` use two properties:

```
subItem.vUrlControlelr
subItem.vUrlAction
```

And generate the URL as:

```
@Url.Action(subItem.vUrlAction,subItem.vUrlControlelr)
```

this should solve the issue.

**EDIT:1**

```
            @foreach (PROC_GET_MENU_BY_USER_Result subItem in subMenu)
            {
                if (subMenu.IndexOf(subItem) == 0)
                {
                    <li  class ='haschildren'> <a href='#'>@subItem.vDescription<span class='arrow'></span></a>
                    <ul class='submenu' style='z-index: 1;'>
                }

                <li><a href='@Url.Action(subItem.vUrlAction,subItem.vUrlControlelr)'>@subItem.vDescription</a>

                @if (subMenu.IndexOf(subItem) == subMenu.Count - 1)
                {
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            }
```

Comment: hi i have done changes as you mentioned                                                                      strMenu = strMenu + "<li><a href=\"@Url.Action(\"" + subItem.vUrlAction + "\",\"" + subItem.vUrlController + "\")\">" + subItem.vDescription + " </a>";         but in url it looks like as     http://localhost:20283/Dashboard/@Url.Action(

Comment: Sorry, but why are you building a `string` in cshtml that contains the `html`? you can directly put the html there. Let me edit my post...

Comment: Anyway, for now, you can use this:
`strMenu = strMenu + "<li> <a href="@Url.Action(subitem.vUrlAction,subitem.vUrlController)"></a>";`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested **SamGhatak**, you should use two properties in your Db. 
But if you don't want to change your `Db` then append a `/` before URl. it will resolve your problem.

```
strMenu = strMenu + "<li><a href='/" + subItem.vUrl + "'>" + subItem.vDescription + " </a>";
```

If you have created two column then It should be like this

```
 strMenu = strMenu + "<li> <a href="@Url.Action(subitem.vurlaction,subitem.vurlcontroller)"></a>";
```

Comment: but its not working in my case it skips project root directory. It just shows action name,Controller Name